# Struggling with lexical scoping and for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, lexical-scope

How do I get the `modify_attr()` function (below) **not** to capture/update the value of b in the following for loop? (simplified version, occurring within a `mainloop()`):

```
for b in range(x):

    button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="<", command=lambda: current_instance.modify_attr(b, -1))
    button.place(x=110, y=80 + 18 * b)
    button = tk.Button(button_frame, text=">", command=lambda: current_instance.modify_attr(b, 1))
    button.place(x=120, y=80 + 18 * b)
```

The goal is to generate two columns of buttons and to bind each button pair to a (somewhat complicated) pair of functions (conditional reduce_by_one / increase_by_one functions).

- **x** = the number of button pairs I need generated
- **current_instance** = a class instance
- **modify_attr** = a class method accepting two arguments (well I guess three if we include self)

My understanding (based on [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2008-October/002109.html) and other things I've read over the past few) is that this issue is a common one.  At its heart, **the problem is that all values of b with respect to modify_attr() wind up equal to `len(x)`** (rather than the value of b at the moment I intend to bind that command to the button).  The result is a series of buttons that are positioned properly (via the b value(s) in `button.place`) but all pointing to the last element in the list they're supposed to be modifying.

I previously encountered this exact problem and was able to work around it using a helper function.  But for some reason I am unable to apply that solution here (again, simplified for clarity):

```
for b in range(len(the_list)):
    def helper_lambda(c):
        return lambda event: refresh_frame(the_list[c])
    window.bind(b + 1, helper_lambda(b))
```

Does that make sense?  Exact same issue, helper_lamdba works like a charm.  Now, in this case, I'm binding a hotkey rather than a button command, but I simply can't get my head around why it would work differently.  Because fundamentally the problem is with the for loop, not the functions within.  But when I implement a helper function in my button loop it fails like a not-a-charm.

Here is my failed attempt to apply that helper strategy:

```
for b in range(x):
    def helper_lambda(c, modifier):
        return lambda event: current_instance.modify_attr(c, modifier)

    button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="<", command=lambda: helper_lambda(b, -1))
    button.place(x=110, y=80 + 18 * b)
    button = tk.Button(button_frame, text=">", command=lambda: helper_lambda(b, 1))
    button.place(x=120, y=80 + 18 * b)
```

What am I doing wrong?  Also, why does it behave this way?  Is anyone using incrementor values outside of for loops?!

Comment: Possibly try defining the `helper_lambda` outside of the `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach may work with few changes:

```
for b in range(x):
    def helper_lambda(c, modifier):
        return lambda: current_instance.modify_attr(c, modifier)  # removed event argument

    button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="<", command=helper_lambda(b, -1))
    button.place(x=110, y=80 + 18 * b)
    button = tk.Button(button_frame, text=">", command=helper_lambda(b, 1))
    button.place(x=150, y=80 + 18 * b)
```

However, you can use `lambda` directly without the helper function:

```
for b in range(x):
    button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="<", command=lambda b=b: current_instance.modify_attr(b, -1))
    button.place(x=110, y=80 + 18 * b)
    button = tk.Button(button_frame, text=">", command=lambda b=b: current_instance.modify_attr(b, 1))
    button.place(x=150, y=80 + 18 * b)
```

Comment: It just assigns a *default* value (`b` from the for loop) to the argument `b`.  Default value is bound when creating the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where `functools.partial` is a better option than a lambda expression.

```
from functools import partial

for b in range(x):

    button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="<", command=partial(current_instance.modify_attr, b, -1))
    button.place(x=110, y=80 + 18 * b)
    button = tk.Button(button_frame, text=">", command=partial(current_instance.modify_attr, b, 1))
    button.place(x=120, y=80 + 18 * b)
```

`partial` receives the *value* of `b` as an argument, rather than simply capturing the *name* `b` for later use.